# Trying to figure out `random` function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I just learned about `random` function.

To my understanding, `random` function takes a value of type which is an instance of `RandomGen` and returns a random value whose value we can specify. On the other hand, `mksdGen` takes an `Int` and generates a random generator which `random` function needs.

I was trying to generate random `Bool` values. In order to do that, I made a function `randomBool`.

```
randomBool :: Int -> Bool
randomBool = fst . random . mkStdGen
```

Then I found a lot more `True`s than `False`s with small numbers.
And I was curious about it and checked as following

```
> length $ takeWhile randomBool [1..]
53667
```

I think this means that for the first 53667 positive integers, `random . mkStdGen` returns `True`, which do not seem to be very random to me.
Is it very normal? Or am I doing something wrong that make `True` happen more easily?

Answer (score 16):

Informally, when you call `mkStdGen` with seeds that are close together you will get two 'similar' generators.  In your example you're actually creating new generators for each seed supplied, and since those seeds are 1, 2, 3, etc., they'll yield similar streams.

When you call `random` with a generator, you actually get back a new generator in the second element of the pair:

```
Prelude System.Random> random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Bool, StdGen)
(True,4041414 40692)
```

So a good idea is to use this provided generator for your next call to `random`.  I.e.,

```
Prelude System.Random> let (i, gen0) = random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Bool, StdGen)
Prelude System.Random> let (j, gen1) = random gen0           :: (Bool, StdGen)
Prelude System.Random> let (k, gen2) = random gen1           :: (Bool, StdGen)
Prelude System.Random> (i, j, k)
(True, False, False)
```

So to make a bunch of random values, you want to *pass the generator as state*.  You can set this up manually via a `State` monad or something, or just use the `randoms` function, which handles passing the generator state for you:

```
Prelude System.Random> take 10 $ randoms (mkStdGen 100) :: [Bool]
[True,False,False,False,False,True,True,False,False,True]
```

If you don't particularly care about being in `IO` (it happens) you can use `randomIO`:

```
Prelude System.Random> import Control.Monad
Prelude System.Random Control.Monad> replicateM 10 randomIO :: IO [Bool]
[True,True,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,True]
```

[This section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) of LYAH might be a useful read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually came up with this question after reading LYAH where I found that the first coin in almost all cases is `True`. (When I checked first few thousands cases, I got a lot more `True` than `False`) Hm... Even though 'close' seeds generate 'similar' generator, I still feel that it is weird that `True` shows up for 50 thousands numbers in a row...

Comment: The problem is that those ~50000 generators seeded from 1-50000 are similar enough such that the first element they each produce is `True`.  Try `random (mkStdGen 100000) :: (Bool, StdGen)` to observe a generator that initially produces a `False`.  

The key is that you should really only *seed* a single generator, rather than seed a bunch of generators with similar values.  Use whatever seed you want, but then use the 'generated generators' to produce additional random values.

Answer (score 3):

Computers are deterministic and can't generate random numbers. Rather, they rely on mathematical formulas that return a distribution of numbers that look random. These are called pseudo-random number generators. However, because of the determinism, we have the problem that if we ran these formulas the same way during each invocation of our program, we would get the same random number generators. Obviously, this is no good, since we want our numbers to be random! Thus, we have to provide the random generator an initial seed value that changes from run-to-run. For most people (i.e., those not doing cryptographical stuff), the random number generator is seeded by the current time. In Haskell, this pseudo-random generator is represented by the `StdGen` type. The `mkStdGen` function is used to create a random number generator with a seed. Unlike C, where there is one global random number generator, in Haskell, you can have as many as you like, and you can create them with different seeds.

However, there is a caveat: since the numbers are pseudo-random, there is no guarantee that random number generators created with different seeds return numbers that look random compared to the other. This means that when you call `randomBool` and give it successive seed values, there is no guarantee that the number you get from the `StdGen` you create is random compared to the `StdGen` seeded with its successor. This is why you get almost 50000 `True`'s.

In order to get data that actually looks random, you need to continue using the same random number generator. If you notice, the `random` Haskell function has a type `StdGen -> (a, StdGen)`. Because Haskell is pure, the `random` function takes a random number generator, generates a pseudo-random value (the first element of the return value) and then returns a new `StdGen` which represents the generator seeded with the original seed, but ready to give a new random number. You need to keep this other `StdGen` around and pass it to the next `random` function in order to get random data.

Here is an example, generating three random bools, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
randomBools :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
randomBools gen = let (a, gen') = random gen
                      (b, gen'') = random gen''
                      (c, gen''') = random gen'''
                   in (a, b, c)
```

Notice how the `gen` variable is "threaded" through the calls to random.

You can simplify passing state by using a state monad. For example,

```
import Control.Monad.State
import System.Random

type MyRandomMonad a = State StdGen a

myRandom :: Random a => MyRandomMonad a
myRandom = do
  gen <- get -- Get the StdGen state from the monad
  let (nextValue, gen') = random gen -- Generate the number, and keep the new StdGen
  put gen' -- Update the StdGen in the monad so subsequent calls generate new random numbers
  return nextValue
```

Now you can write the `randomBools` function as:

```
randomBools' :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
randomBools' gen = fst $ runState doGenerate gen
  where doGenerate = do
          a <- myRandom
          b <- myRandom
          c <- myRandom
          return (a, b, c)
```

If you want to generate a (finite) list of `Bool`s, you can do

```
randomBoolList :: StdGen -> Int -> ([Bool], StdGen)
randomBoolList gen length = runState (replicateM length myRandom) gen
```

Notice how we return the `StdGen` as the second element of the returned pair, to allow it to be given to new functions.

More simply, if you just want to generate an infinite list of random values of the same type from an `StdGen`, you can use the `randoms` function. This has the signature `(RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]`. To generate an infinite list of `Bool` using a starting seed of `x`, you simply run `randoms (mkStdGen x)`. You can implement your example using `length $ takeWhile id (randoms (mkStdGen x))`. You should verify that you get different values for different initial values of `x`, but always the same value if you supply the same `x`.

Finally, if you don't care about being tied to the `IO` monad, Haskell also provides a global random number generator, much like imperative languages. Calling the function `randomIO` in the `IO` monad will give you a random value of whatever type you like (as long as it is an instance of the `Random` typeclass, at least). You can use this similarly to `myRandom` above, except in the `IO` monad. This has the added convenience that it is pre-seeded by the Haskell runtime, meaning you don't have to even worry about creating an `StdGen`. So, to create a random list of 10 `Bool`s in the `IO` monad, all you have to do is `replicateM 10 randomIO :: IO [Bool].`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Strictly, computers _can_ produce random numbers if you have a suitable hardware source. The latest Intel processors even added a machine code instruction for this purpose... (Yes, this is only tangentially related to the point you were trying to make.)

Answer (score 2):

A random generator created by `mkStdGen` doesn't necessarily generate a random value as its first result. To generate the next random number, use the random generator returned by the previous `random` call.

For example, this code generates 10 `Bool`s.

```
take 10 $ unfoldr (Just . random) (mkStdGen 1) :: [Bool]
```

Comment: To elaborate on this: the random generator isn't guaranteed to have a random distribution over the seed values, but it is guaranteed to give a random distribution over sequences of produced values.